# How to change bokeh logo

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there anyway to set my own logo on a bokeh plot?  I would like to set my own .png instead of using the bokeh colorful circle.

Referring specifically to changing the 
[image: bokeh image on the toolbar]

Thanks

Comment: @JGreenwell I don't think this question is related to your link. This question is about a specific logo that appears on all plots, in a banner area. This question is not about how to generally plot a custom image file. However, there do appear to be other duplicates that do ask about the logo issue ... I can't determine if any of them actually have an up-to-date answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12` this is an [open feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3820). For now your only options are to grey-out the logo, or to remove it entirely.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  While I have your attention, I would like to know if there is a solution to the following bokeh + PyQt question: (I am running into the same issue) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303912/bokeh-tools-not-working-in-qwebview