# How to enable bokeh tools in a pyqt QWebview

Tags: python, pyqt4, bokeh

1. I load a bokeh html plot into QWebview() like this (`path` is the location of the html file)

`path = os.path.join(self._outstream, __config__['HTML_FILENAME'])
 view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
 view.load(QtCore.QUrl(path))`

2. The graph displays good, but none of the tools work (i.e. box zoom, reset, etc.) . Javascript is enabled on the `QWebPage`.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to get this working?
3. also see: 
   [Bokeh tools not working in QWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303912/bokeh-tools-not-working-in-qwebview)

Qt version: 4.8.7
PyQt version: 4.11.4

With javascript console output enabled:
When I LOAD the graph (i.e. `view.load`) the following messages are printed

`c:%5CUsers%5C...[path omitted] line 79: Bokeh: Float64Array is not supported. Using generic Array instead.
c:%5CUsers%5C...[path omitted] line 18: Bokeh: setting prefix to
c:%5CUsers%5C...[path omitted] line 19: Bokeh: setting log level to: 'info'`

When I click the 'boxzoom' tool, the following message is printed.

`c:%5CUsers%5C...[path omitted] line 79: Bokeh: 'point' selection not available for Ray`

To reiterate, the tool is not functioning.  However, when i mouse over the tool, the correct tooltip is displayed and it does show the mouse over event i.e. [image]

Comment: Is there a way to see JS console output in `QWebview` widgets?

Comment: Yeah, i'll try that now

Comment: Also what version of Qt? It may be that a newer Qt based on Chromium is needed.

Comment: My guess is that Qt 4.8 is simply too old.

Comment: Did you ever get this one figured out?

Comment: I tried to do this recently. I believe it doesn't work because the version of WebKit that the QWebView runs off of is too old and some of the items that BokehJS call do not exist in the older version of WebKit.

Comment: Has anyone had any success with this?